# How to run a java class as a process

Tags: java, process

Part of my program will need to execute another java program I wrote as a process, if I write:

```
       Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
       Process process = runtime.exec(<path to class file>);
```

Why does this not work? The error tells me its not a vlaid win32 application.

Comment: Try runtime.exec("java <your_class_name>");

Comment: You could probably run the java binary as process, with a parameter pointing to your class file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's right: a class file is not a valid Win32 application. You need to execute the class file with the Java runtime:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = runtime.exec("java [YourClassName]");
```

This assumes that you have a `main` method in your class.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it doesn't work because it is NOT a win32 application.

Class files are run by the java virtual machine, not by the Windows operating system.  You could try feeding the command 'java -jar .jar, once you've packaged your class file and the other class files that it needs in a jar file.

Answer (score 0):

`(<path to class file>)` ... to the jar? or to the myClass.class?

can you run the class in a console:

```
java -jar myClass.jar
```